# How to upgrade Openshift Origin Docker to latest version?

Tags: docker, openshift, openshift-origin

We are running Openshift Origin which got installed by using the Ansible playbooks.

This by default installed docker 1.9.1, now we have to upgrade it to the latest version because of frequent crashes of docker.

But seems like Origin package dependent on docker 1.9.1.

So, How do I upgrade docker to latest version which is recognizable by Origin?

Origin 1.4.1, RHEL 7.2

Comment: It's not clear which OS and what version of OpenShift Origin you are using. Is it possible that you are using some old version and that's why it depends on old version of Docker?

Answer (score 0):

[Origin 1.4.1 requires Docker 1.12 and RedHat/CentOS 7.3](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.4/install_config/install/prerequisites.html). (the docs are for OCP 3.4 but they match with Origin 1.4)

Upgrading RHEL to 7.3 should also let you install Docker 1.12:

```
(master-prod-public)root@master1:~# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo)
(master-prod-public)root@master1:~# docker version
Client:
 Version:         1.12.6
 API version:     1.24
 Package version: docker-common-1.12.6-16.el7.x86_64
 Go version:      go1.7.4
 Git commit:      3a094bd/1.12.6
 Built:           Tue Mar 21 13:30:59 2017
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:         1.12.6
 API version:     1.24
 Package version: docker-common-1.12.6-16.el7.x86_64
 Go version:      go1.7.4
 Git commit:      3a094bd/1.12.6
 Built:           Tue Mar 21 13:30:59 2017
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64
```

Also check if there are any leftover versionlocks:

(m

```
aster-prod-public)root@master1:~# yum versionlock
Loaded plugins: search-disabled-repos, versionlock
# list of locked packages...
versionlock list done
```